# Access specifiers and rvalue references

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following piece of code, which doesn't compile (the compiler complains that B::fn is inaccessible).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class B
{
    public:
    void fn(T &&obj)
    {
        cout<<"base version\n";
    }
};

template<typename T>
class A : public B<T>
{
    private:
    using B<T>::fn;

    public:
    void fn(const T &obj)
    {
        cout<<"derived version\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A<int *> a;
    a.fn(new int(5));
}
```

To make the code work, it seems that I can

1. define a separate `void fn(T &&obj)`, in the derived class, or,
2. make the inheritance private and do away with the access specifier

Could anyone please explain why my current code doesn't work, but the above approaches do?

[UPDATE]: I undersand that B::fn would be private. The reason I'm confused is that `class A : private B<T>` fixes the problem.

Comment: This `private: using B<T>::fn;` looks very much like a private member - inaccessible. It might be public in `B`, but is made private in `A`.

Comment: But then, why don't I get the same complaint when I inherit as private?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with:

```
private:
using B<T>::fn;
```

`B<T>::fn` is visible, but *private*.
replace by `public` and it would also be public.

If you remove the `using B<T>::fn;`, the `B<T>::fn` is hidden by `A::fn`,
so the call in main calls `A::fn`.

Comment: But then, why don't I get the same complaint when I inherit as private?

Comment: @user2308211: It has nothing to do with private inheritance, but by the fact that you don't *unhide* `B<T>::fn` with `using`.